# when a certain word is found in a cell, insert a line

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro which when a button is clicked, all the information is transfered from one spreadsheet onto a form (also excel sheet). I just can't seem to get one thing right: insert lines when I reach the bottom of the form. At the bottom of the form, in column A, it says:additional. I want to insert a line every time I come in contact with this cell. Please help!

For example:

```
 for i = 1 to lastline
worksheet1.Range("A" & i).value = worksheet2.Range("A" & i)

if worksheet1.Range("A" & i).value contains "additional"  'please help me write this line
insert a line above this cell 'please help me write this line
end if
next i
```

Please help!!! Thanks in advance! Let me know if my question makes any sense :)

Comment: Insert a line where? Sheet1 or sheet2? Both sheets?

Comment: Thanks Tim for replying! Insert a line in Sheet1 :) Thanks! I am really lost right now. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim tmp, skip As Long

skip = 0

For i = 1 To lastline
    tmp = worksheet2.Range("A" & i).Value
    If LCase(tmp) Like "*additional*" Then skip = skip + 1
    worksheet1.Cells(i + skip, 1).Value = tmp
Next i
```